# ENUM with description on VS Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, visual-studio-code

Just to contextualize, I'm using visual studio code, and I created a new project (webapplication) by "yo aspnet".

I tried to create a ENUM with description, but I don't know what is wrong with this code. The error is:

> "The type or namespace name 'DescriptionAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [dnxcore50] DescriptionAttribute.DescriptionAttribute(string description)".

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public enum Category
{
  [DescriptionAttribute("Habitação")]HABITACAO = 1, 
  [DescriptionAttribute("Cuidados Pessoais")]CUIDADOSPESSOAIS = 2,
  [DescriptionAttribute("Saúde")]SAUDE = 3,
  [DescriptionAttribute("Outros")]OUTROS = 999
}
```

Comment: Have you added a reference to `System.dll`?

Comment: Not sure why it's not working, but FYI you can use `[Description()]` instead of `[DescriptionAttribute()]` - the `Attribute` part is inferred automatically.

Comment: What target version of .Net *exactly* is your [project configured](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx) to build to?

Comment: Hi! Alejandro, I'm not sure how to add a reference on Visual Studio Code. I was looking for it, but until now, I couldnt find the answer... ---- Blorgbeard, I tried to use "Attribute" too, but the same error... ---- Erik, it's aspnet5. Thank you

Comment: you can use [Display(Name="customValue"]. Check [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776908/Dealing-with-Enum-in-MVC)

Comment: It works! Finally!! Thank you!